# iPhone: Issue when adding json NSString into NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone

I am setting a json output like below. It is a NSString.

```
    MyNSString = {
    title = FirstOne;
    titleno = 95;
}

MyNSString = {
    title = SecondOne;
    titleno = 96;
}
```

I have to add like the above json multiple strings into an NSArray (or) NSMutableArray. I am trying to add in NSMutableArray. When i want to add like the above json string into an NSMutableArray, the output comes like below, with \n  .

```
[outNSMutableArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", MyNSString] ];

    (
        "{\n  \"title\" : \"FirstOne\",\n  \"titleno\" : \"95\"\n}",
        "{\n  \"title\" : \"SecondOne\",\n  \"titleno\" : \"96\"\n}"
    )
```

I want this to be like below, without "\n \" added.

```
[ {"title":"FirstOne","titleno":95},{"title":"SecondOne","titleno":96}]
```

How can i correct this? Could someone help?

Comment: @Luke has provided the solution. Don't forgot to replace single space and \ character with blank space to get expected output.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString* string = [myJSONString stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString: @"\n" withString: @""];
```

EDIT:

So you have this:

```
[outNSMutableArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", MyNSString] ];
```

Change it to this:

```
NSString* str = [MyNSString stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString: @"\n" withString: @""];
[outNSMutableArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", str] ];
```

Comment: It is not in NSString. \n \ is added only after added into outNSMutableArray.

Comment: Yes, but when you output it then you can run this filter. What's wrong with that?

Comment: I am sorry i'm not able to get it. I need to get the output only as an Array.

Comment: Added in another example for you.

Comment: I am getting this error-> error: Automatic Reference Counting Issue: Receiver type 'NSString' for instance message does not declare a method with selector 'stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString:withString:'

Comment: Did you have a quick look online? Quite a common error message it seems.